# Error in Postgres function execution

Tags: postgresql-9.2

I am trying to execute this function but it is giving me error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "return"
LINE 12:  return;
```

what's wrong with this line ?? I am using Postgres(9.2).

```
create or replace function conditional_tax(taxPerc decimal(5),minSal decimal(5))   returns SETOF emp as
$body$
declare r emp%rowtype;

begin
  For r in select * from emp where salary > minSal
  Loop
    r.salary = r.salary - (r.salary * taxPerc /100) ;
    return next r;
  End Loop
 return;
end
$body$
Language 'plpgsql';
```

Answer (score 1):

There's *nothing* wrong with that line. However, there *is* something wrong with the previous line.

You're meant to terminate the `end loop` with a semi-colon `;`. The [syntax chart](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html) is:

```
[ <<label>> ]
LOOP
    statements
END LOOP [ label ];
```

Answer (score 1):

This is much simpler. Just plain SQL. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/f27a1/1)

```
create or replace function conditional_tax(
    taxPerc decimal(5),
    minSal decimal(5)
) returns SETOF decimal(5) as $body$

select salary * (1 - taxPerc / 100) as salary
from emp
where salary > minSal
;

$body$ language sql;
```